# performing function on values in dataframe and replacing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to perform a function on every value in a column of a pandas data frame and replace the old value with the new one. for example, going through every value in the column and replacing it with the value plus one. I have been trying things like the code below but it is not replacing the values.

```
for row in df["src"]:
    try:
            df["src"]= (function)
    except:
            print ("Error")
```

An example of column is below, all values are strings.

```
src

59.166.0.0
59.166.0.7
175.45.176.2
.
.
.
59.166.0.4
```

Comment: Can you explain more? Do you need `df["src"].apply(func)` ?

Comment: I want to go through each row in a column perform a function on that value and then replace the original value with the new one. I havent used .apply before so ill try it.

Comment: Is possible create some data sample if solution with `apply` not working like you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'src':['192.168.0.1','192.168.0.10', '']})
print (df)
            src
0   192.168.0.1
1  192.168.0.10
2              

def func(x):
    try:
        x = int(ipaddress.ip_address(x))
        return x
    except:
        return 0

df["src"] = df["src"].apply(func)
print (df)
          src
0  3232235521
1  3232235530
2           0
```

Comment: The simplest solution, the python way... could just modify to return x+1 to suit the mentioned example in the question.

Comment: @Eswar - simpiest is return `x + 1`

Comment: Can also the lamda functionality...just another alternate

Comment: @Eswar - exactly, it depends of complicated of function.

Comment: this is giving me error ('int' object is not callable), the function is just "x = int(ipaddress.ip_address(x))".

Comment: @dmnte - I understand, give em a sec.

Comment: @dmnte - What do you need return if value is not valid?

Comment: Thank you for your help this is working. I will just return 0 for non valid values

Comment: returning `x+1` is more pythonic!

Answer (score 1):

More none pandas solution:

```
def func(x):
    #code here
    return x

df["src"] = map(func,df['src'])
```

Or:

```
def func(x):
    #code here
    return x

df["src"] = [func(i) for i in df['src']]
```

Comment: Why convert to list?